# Assign tag to all VMs at once

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, tags

I want to add the same tag value for all VM's in every resouce group in Azure.

I already prepared a script, but PS doesn't want to proceed with this, because of object to string conversion thingy.

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM

$VMs | Foreach-Object {
$t = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $VMs.Name -ResourceGroupName $VMs.ResourceGroupName
Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ Funding="..."} -ResourceId $t.ResourceId -Force
}
```

But how can I do loops, when it asks for a string, when objects parsed to loop must clearly be object? Am I forced to prepare external list in a txt file and parse values from there as strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `ForEach-Object` loop, you should use the automatic variable `$_` to target that one particular object. Now you are sending arrays to the `Get-AzureRmResource` cmdlet:

```
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM

$VMs | Foreach-Object {
    $t = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName
    Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ Funding="..."} -ResourceId $t.ResourceId -Force
}
```

Suppose you have three VMs you get back from `$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM`
(I faked that here using an array of  [PSCustomObject] objects)

```
$VMs = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'VM1'; ResourceGroupName = 'VM1_Resource'},
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'VM2'; ResourceGroupName = 'VM2_Resource'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'VM3'; ResourceGroupName = 'VM3_Resource'}
)
```

Then performing `$VMs.Name` results in (Object[]) **array** `'VM1','VM2','VM3'`

and performing `$VMs.ResourceGroupName` results in an **array** `'VM1_Resource','VM2_Resource','VM3_Resource'`

Inside the loop however, the variable `$_` represents only one of these VM's in turn, so for the first iteration `$_.Name` is a **string** `"VM1"` etc.

Hope that explains your *object to string conversion thingy.*

Comment: Yes, that explains it perfectly. Thank you very much!